# Why does an empty Image source prevent MouseDown event?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, events

```
private void Init()
{  
   Image image = new Image();
   image.Source = null;

   image.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(image_MouseDown);
   grid.Children.Add(image);
}

private void image_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  Console.WriteLine("IN");
}
```

When the Image control have an empty source, the MouseDown event will never fire. I then tried to add a border to my grid, add the Image as a children to the border and adding the event to the border instead of the Image, but I had the same result.

I used Snoop to see what handled the event and it's the parent of my grid (a ScrollViewer).

Comment: Null Source means no rendered output means no mouse events. In case of the Border, set its Background property to e.g. Transparent.

Comment: Thank you very much. Explanation + alternative solution. +1

Comment: Specifically,WPF does a hit test in the control stack from top to bottom looking for the first control that drew a pixel.  If there is no image and no background the hit test will fall through to the next element.